# most simple way to start a new process/thread in PHP

Tags: php, multithreading, performance, process

Scenario:

1. Shared hosting, so no ability to install new extensions + no CRON
2. A submitted request needs to perform some heavy processes.
3. I want the answer to the client to go as fast as possible, and the heavy lifting to continue immediately, but not stop the client.
4. can be on a new  thread (if it is possible) also no problem with starting a new process.

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: PHP cannot (currently) be multi-threaded. *Much* to my regular displeasure.

Comment: Well, some things can be emulated.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

On *nix:

```
exec('/path/to/executable > /dev/null 2>&1 &');
```

On Windows:

```
$WshShell = new COM('WScript.Shell'); 
$oExec = $WshShell->Run('C:\path\to\executable.exe', 0, false);
```

Both of these will spawn a new process that will run a-synchronously, completely disconnected from the parent. As long as your host allows you to do it.

Comment: can I change the /dev/null to a log file of my choosing?

Comment: I think so, as long as you redirect STDOUT *and* STDERR to somewhere that isn't the parent process, and suffix with `&`, it should work. TBH, I have always just `/dev/null`ed it, so really you'll just have to suck it and see...

Comment: Start an arbitrary external process on shared hosting? Good luck with that.

Comment: @JBNizet I can start external PHP scripts on mine doing exactly as above, and they will actually run I think forever - I had one running for over a week as an experiment once.

Comment: Wow. You're much luckier than me then :-)

Answer (score 4):

To complement @DaveRandom's answer: you don't actually **need** to redirect `STDERR` to `STDOUT` (with `2>&1`).

You need to redirect `STDOUT` though, if you want to prevent the parent process from hanging waiting for the child to finish. This is required cause `exec` will return the last line of the output of the child process, therefore, it needs to wait for the child's `STDOUT` to be closed.

That doesn't mean you need to redirect it to `/dev/null`. You can redirect it to some other file, or even to some other file descriptor (like `STDERR`: `1>&2`).

- `exec('/path/to/executable')`: will start a new process and wait for it to finish (i.e. blocking the parent process).
- `exec('/path/to/executable &')`: basically the same as the above.
- `$pid = exec('/path/to/executable > /dev/null & echo $!')`: will start a process in the background, with child and parent processes running in parallel. The output of `/path/to/executable` will be discarded, and `$pid` will receive the PID of the child process.

Using `2>&1` is actually not necessary, cause `exec` ignores the `STDERR` of the child process. It is also probably undesirable cause it will make it harder to find some errors, cause they will be just silently thrown away. If you omit `2>&1`, you can pipe the `STDERR` of the parent process to some log file, that can be checked later when something goes wrong:

```
php /path/to/script.php 2>> /var/log/script_error.log
```

By using the above to start the script which triggers the child processes, everything that `script.php` **and** any child process write to `STDERR` will be written to the log file.

Answer (score 3):

You can google by key: php continue processing after closing connection.

The following links that relate to your problem, are:

- [Continue processing after closing connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4806637/continue-processing-after-closing-connection)
- http://php-fpm.org/wiki/Features#fastcgi_finish_request.28.29
- http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.connection-handling.php

You can use belong command to continue executing without user aborting

```
ignore_user_abort(true);
set_time_limit(0);
```

You use fastcgi_finish_request to alert client to stop the response output. And your scripts will continue to be executed.

An example:

```
// redirecting...
ignore_user_abort(true);
set_time_limit(0);
header("Location: ".$redirectUrl, true);
header("Connection: close", true);
header("Content-Length: 0", true);
ob_end_flush();
flush();
fastcgi_finish_request(); // important when using php-fpm!

sleep (5); // User won't feel this sleep because he'll already be away

// do some work after user has been redirected
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. You should review the formatting of your answer. As of now, it seems that you put everything in a code block, while there is part of your answer that is not code.

Answer (score 1):

There are no threads in PHP. You could cheat by sending back an HTML page that triggers an Ajax call to start the heavy process in a new request. But if it's shared hosting, my guess is that you'll quickly hit the limits on memory, time or CPU usage imposed by your hosting provider.

Comment: [Evidently, there are threads in PHP now](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/class.thread.php) but you may have to [install them](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/pthreads.installation.php). However, I only just learned this tonight, so I haven't tried it yet.

Answer (score -1):

```
$WshShell = new COM('WScript.Shell');
$oExec    = $WshShell->Run('C:\xampp\php\php.exe C:\xampp\htdocs\test.php -a asdf', 0, true);
```

Cannot pass argv to test.php.

```
var_dump($argv);
```