# SMTP mail really slow

Tags: php, zend-framework, smtp

So I have a problem with SMTP mail, I have a Zend Framework 2 application, and when the user signs up on the site I send him an confirmation email.

The problem is that when the user click on submit it takes about 3-5 seconds on page load, and that's because of the smtp email that is sending, if I take the part out which sends the email, the answer is instant.

I'm using SMTP from gmail, do you guys have any tips how to solve this?

Comment: May be it is server's problem.

Comment: you can extract the mailing process from the app, maybe put it in a queue and use a background process or a cronjob to send it

Comment: Try to check your code in controller, maybe it has slow performace?

Comment: @Victor Well it's using the basic MAIL code from ZF core, if I take the part out which sends the email the response time is instant.

Comment: I found this article: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16185240/the-zend-framework-2-send-email-is-too-slowgoogle-smtp-server I wil try to  make a bash script or something for sending emails...

Answer (score 0):

Actually, PHP documentation doesn't recommend to use the PHP's `mail()` function to send an email on page load. Instead, it would be much faster to send emails in background. For example, create the `outgoing_mail` table in your database, and save your messages there when page is loaded. Then, create a `cron` scheduled task which runs your PHP script that would enumerate all pending messages and send them in turn. This way, you will have quick page load time and mail sent.