# PHP+Apache - Close connection and process data

Tags: php, apache

I have a PHP application which receives data from the user. I would like the script to send a quick response, close the connection with the browser and then process the data. My main concern is that as the data processing takes quite a while and there are many concurrent users on the website, I will soon get to a point where there are too many open connections. Any ides on how I could do this?

Comment: Check the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4856241/108574 . This is a duplicate question.

Comment: You are right He Siming, I got to the same answer via another way and indicated this solution here below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I've found the solution I needed. Here following is the PHP code I'm using. After this code I can keep processing as I need:

```
// http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.connection-handling.php#71172
ob_end_clean();
header("Connection: close");
ignore_user_abort();    // optional
ob_start();
echo $user_message;
$size = ob_get_length();
header("Content-Length: $size");
ob_end_flush();         // Strange behaviour, will not work
flush();
```

Answer (score 0):

Submit the user's data to a database.  Have a cronjob take care of the processing.  If the user needs to see the result afterwards, use polling with Ajax to wait until the data is processed.  A cronjob is a command that gets executed every set period of time on a server.  You can make it execute a PHP script that does the processing every minute or whatever you need.

Answer (score 0):

I think [gearman](http://gearman.org/) would be a good solution.

As you say, running out of resources, because of running to many processes is the big issue, this is one of the things a queuing system like gearman handles. So what ever you do, you need to queue the work.