# PHP sending E-Mail via SMTP very slow

Tags: php, email, smtp

i wrote a script using swift mailer to send e-mails via smtp. I noticed that it takes a fairly long time for the script to load due to the smtp sending.

I thought it would be a good idea to put the sending of that email into a seperate file. The only problem i have now is that i need to open the file.

I don't want to use fopen or anything like that because i would like that file to run "in the background" so to speak.

Is that possible without a cronjob? Is there a way to just fire that file without the user noticing it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Continue processing after closing connection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4806637/continue-processing-after-closing-connection)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use [exec](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php) to do this by calling command line php

```
exec('php script.php >/dev/null 2>&1 &');
```

Answer (score 0):

another option is to have a cron script and queue table (if you have a low traffic)

Bad thing about running  php background jobs is a denial of service risk. Cron can run every 2 minutes, kill another running instances and process mail queue. 
Running background jobs through spawning new processes is risky. And you have to remember - never pass user-defined variable to a background process.

Comment: he said he doesn't want cron. not sure what DoS has to do with it. and of course you can parse user-defined variables to background script, just sanatise them first,

Comment: Yes, you're right about "he doesn't want cron". But it's better to have a cron controlled job than to rely on users not to spawn a thousand execs, I think. And a problem with sanitizing is - if you have a team (or a buddy willing to help) and someone forgets about sanitizing.

Comment: lol, i guess you never add any user provided information in to a database either.

Comment: kek. Add user-provided data to a database is a one thing, it's just a little sql-injection. Running this data through a system shell... well, it's a bad idea.

Comment: if someone screws your database you can loose/share data. If someone screws your shell - you loose control of the system.